# Using wildcard route matching in FW/1

Tags: coldfusion, fw1

I am trying to use the wildcard match on routes in FW/1 v 3.5.

**Application.cfc**

```
component  extends="framework.one"  {

  this.name= "Wildcard7";

  variables.framework = {
    home = 'main.home',
    action = 'fuseaction',
    baseURL = 'useCgiScriptName',
    trace = isDebugMode()
    };

  variables.framework.routes = [
    { "main/home"               = "main/home"},
    { "*"                       = "main/404"}
  ];

}
```

When I run the page, without specifying an action, I get the main/404 page instead of main/home

** FW/1 trace**

[image]

How can I get main/404 to run only on invalid pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run the page, without specifying an action, I get the main/404 page instead of main/home

I assume you are trying to access the page like so - `your.domain/index.cfm/main`. *Note the lack of the `home` action.*

Based on your routes, your first route is saying if the path supplied equals "main/home" then point to the view `main/home`. If there is an action of `home` in a `main.cfc` controller then that will be ran prior to rendering the view.

Leaving off the action, `home`, would not match any of your current routes; resulting in your wildcard catching it. You would need to handle it by including another route like `{"main" = "main"}`.

**UPDATE:**

To access `main/home` from `your.domain/index.cfm`, you can try passing a route of `{"/" = "main/home"}`. I would suggest this being above your wildcard and below any other routes to avoid any freak matches.

Comment: I want to go to `your.domain/index.cfm` In other words the page defined in `home=main.home`

Comment: You can use a route that matches "/". I've updated my answer.

Comment: In my experience a route of { "/" = "/main/default" } matches way to many URLs. I experimented $GET/$ and the like. Not satisfactory.

Comment: Based on his question, it seemed like he was trying to match the root. You could always match more specific to the request type but I also would only use this at the bottom of my list of routes just before catching any "404" pages. Typically, I prefer to be thorough and match each page specifically by a given route/pattern and return 404 for everything else with a wildcard.